# How to set a Default Value to KeyboardTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, material-ui

I use **KeyboardTimePicker** material ui, and fetch time of service like "10:20"
How can I set this time ("10:20") as default?
Currently, when I set this time, I get the Invalid Time Format
[image: error] :

```
 const timeDefaultProps = {
    label: props.label,
    variant: "inline",
    inputVariant: "outlined",
    ampm: false,
    showTodayButton: true,
    format: "HH:mm",
    value: props.value , ///->props.value is "10:20"

    onChange: (date) => props.onChange(moment(date).format("HH:mm")),

    onBlur: (event) => {
      setBlured(false);
    },
    onFocus: () => {
      setBlured(true);
    },
    keyboardIcon: (
      <TimeIcon
        className={clsx(
          classes.calendarIcon,
          classes.calendarIconKeyboardPicker
        )}
      />
    ), 
  };

  <KeyboardTimePicker {...timeDefaultProps} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (assuming this is the correct link: [https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardTimePicker#:~:text=value%20*-,ParsableDate,-Picker%20value](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardTimePicker#:%7E:text=value%20*-,ParsableDate,-Picker%20value)) seems to suggest that it requires a ParsableDate. I'd guess a `date` object will do the trick.

In the examples there also appears to be a placeholder prop, although I couldn't see that in the documentation linked above. This could potentially also be what you're looking for (if you only want to use it as the starting value before a user has chosen anything).